# Как сделать чтобы таймер выполнил действие после его отсчета

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,Registry,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  reg: TRegistry;
  sec : Integer;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  procedure formclose;
  begin
    form1.close
  end;
begin
  Application.Run;
  reg:=TRegistry.Create;
  reg.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  reg.Openkey('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVerson\Policies\System',True);
  reg.WriteString('RegistryTools','1');
  reg.CloseKey;
  reg.Free;
end;

end.
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтоб после открытия программы не надо было нажимать на кнопку в форме, а таймер сам после его окончания блокировал диспечер.
Но, как бы я не пытался, таймер выводит пустую форму, а диспечер не блокируется

Comment: "блокировал диспечер" - что это значит?

Comment: что `Application.Run` у вас в коде формы?

Comment: @Igor возможно автор пытается отключить работу Диспетчера задач с помощью настройки политик через реестр. Правда почему-то пишет не тот ключ да еще и с некорректным именем и типом данных, и вероятно ждет что открытый диспетчер внезапно закроется.

Comment: @teran я о чем-то подобном догадывался :). Хотелось бы, чтобы автор внятно объяснил задачу, которую он пытается решить, а не говорил недомолвками.

Comment: если что, ключ для отключения диспетчера задач - `DisableTaskMgr`, и писать его надо с помощью `reg.WriteInteger('DisableTaskMgr', 1)`

Comment: а единоразовое действие чтобы при старте выполнить, следует использовать событие `FormCreate`, а не  приплептать костыль в виде таймера.